# Wordpress template pages not being displayed in 3.2 :|

Tags: wordpress

Few months ago, I developed two template pages on wordpress 3.1 and they were working fine. Now, I installed latest wordpress software. I created a new page with the same name and selected the template. But the link is showing a "404 Not Found" error.

My site URL goes like this: http://localhost/myBlog/about

where "about page" has to use a template. The same permalink is shown when creating the page but viewing page is showing 404 error. It's weird. May be some permalink issue?

Comment: If you create a new page using the default template does it work? It would be strange for the templated page to 404, but a regular page not to. In which case your problem has nothing to do with templates.

Comment: yes, pages are not working at all :| even plain page, when created, shows a 404 page not found error! :(

Comment: Is this a new installation or an upgrade of an existing installation?

Comment: I installed fresh copy, I removed the old db and wordpress installation first, and then installed new one and copied only the theme folder.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. See my proposed answer below. Personally I always use the built-in WP upgrade mechanism. It works really well. You should backup your db and wordpress directory prior to upgrade.

Comment: There is also a dedicated WP stack exchange site you may want to use - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ . They tend to be better at WP configuration or api questions. SO is good for programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming this is a new installation and not an upgrade, I am guessing that your permalink structure is messed up. There are a couple ways to fix this. In general, Wordpress tries to modify your .htaccess file itself.

Go to your old installation and look under Settings -> Permalinks. If it is different from your new install, then change them to be the same and save. If they are the same, then change it to something else and then change it back. This should force Wordpress to resave the settings to your .htaccess file. If it can't write to the file it should tell you.

Alternatively you could look at the .htaccess file of your old installation and copy the values there over to your new installation. Although I think letting WP do it for you is probably the safer route.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your database, You need to go to the wp-options table and change the url there. The other options there. Were you working on a local server?

Comment: What URL to change? yes im working on local server. I've configured permalinks as /%category%/%postname%

Comment: I thought you had taken it on-line. I would suggest reinstalling your wordpress, taking out spaces on your functions.php. Also place your question on http://www.wordpress.org, you will get more responses on the forum.